# Equivalent query replace where to find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Home.where(code: "x123").where.not(state_id: 1)
```

How can I use a equivalent query but instead of using "where" I want  to use find_by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`find_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by) returns a single record (first matching the specified conditions), so there is no way (and sense) to do what you want.

## EDIT

> sure! But I want only one object!

The following query would do it then (it will search for a code `123` and any `state_id` except for `1`. And it returns a first record matching this condition):

```
Home.find_by(code: '123', state_id: State.ids - [1])
```

Comment: sure! But I want only one object!

Comment: But I don't know how to use "not" in find_by

Comment: @dijiri make sure to check the latest answer edit, it will search for a code `123` and any `state_id` except for `1`. And it returns a first record matching this condition.

Comment: this will make an additional database call for `State.ids` and is also not very idiomatic for rails. `where(...).first` is the standard way of loading a single object using where conditions.

Comment: @omnikron I realize that, but OP clearly stated `I want to use find_by` :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko fair enough! the customer is always right :)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to return a single object you can simply use [`first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first):

`Home.where(code: "x123").where.not(state_id: 1).first`

If the reason you want to use `find_by` is because you want missing records to raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` then you can use [`first!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first-21) instead, which will do exactly that.